# Fast way to create numpy 1d bool array with known nonzero entry indexes

Tags: python, numpy

Given a `1d` `np.ndarray` containing a list of indexes that is `True`: `[1, 2, 4]`, and length of the target `np.ndarray`: `6`

How can we quickly construct the actual `np.ndarray` which should be `[False, True, True, False, True, False]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
idx = [1,2,3]
s = 6
a = np.zeros(s,dtype=bool)
a[idx] = True
```

output:

```
[False  True  True  True False False]
```

Comment: Dude you are incredible! And so is numpy!

Comment: Yes! I will accept your answer as soon as Stackoverflow allows me, you answered too quick!

Comment: Oh, did not know there is a time limit. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866197/or-operation-of-multiple-1d-numpy-ndarray Do you think you can answer this one as well?

Comment: @HuadongFeng Please check my answer on that and see if it is what you are looking for. Thank you.