# Or operation of multiple 1d numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple `bool` `np.ndarray` of same shape, e.g.:

```
a1 = [T, F, F]
a2 = [F, F, T]
a3 = [F, T, F]
```

How can I apply the `or` operation maybe something like this and get the result `[T, T, T]`?

```
res = Or([a1, a2, a3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want this:

```
a1 = [True, False, False]
a2 = [False, False, True]
a3 = [False, True, False]
res = np.vstack([a1,a2,a3]).any(axis=0)
```

or equally:

```
res = np.logical_or.reduce([a1,a2,a3])
```

(I expect reduce to be faster or similar performance as stack). There are also many more ways to achieve this. I expect these to be faster than others.

output:

```
[ True  True  True]
```